# Grouping or Clustering Points that are within 45 miles of each other using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, clustering, grouping

I have a project in ArcGIS (ArcMap 10.2) where I want to identify naturally occurring dense spots of points and then form groups in that dense area, where points are within 45 miles of each other. This would mean that not so dense areas will be left out and not become part of any group?

I don't have access to **`Point Density`** tool. I run Python code for Grouping Analysis but I get errors due to Python or GIS version mismatch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an Advanced license, you could use the [Aggregate Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00700000002s000000) tool.  If you need to get the attributes from the original points tied back to these aggregated points, you can do a Spatial Join.

Comment: Thanks, crmackey!! Aggregate Points worked beautifully along with spatial join.

Comment: This seems great, but how do I turn the aggregate points into shapes? In the join table I have OUTPUT_FID and INPUT_FID columns. I did the join, but that gives me multiple points per aggregate point if that makes sense and it's in a table, not visible on the map.

Comment: Now I'm seeing the shape results and the table when I do aggregate points. Must have been my mistake the first time.